# Pentatonic Scale and Chord Qualities

Tags: theory, chord-theory, chord-progressions

I am trying to play the pentatonic in the Key of G-Major. But like in Major scales we have the sequence Maj-min-min-Maj-Maj-min-dim, is there something for Pentatonic as well.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The harmonized (chord) scale for pentatonic scales is interesting.

G major scale: `G A B C D E F#`

G major pentatonic scale: `G A B D E`

By stacking G major scale notes we get the
G major chord scale: `G Am Bm C D Em F#dim`

The G major pentatonic chord scale can use the same chords as a subset of the G major scale.  But if we stack just pentatonic notes we get some other possibilities because the thirds of some of the chords are missing.

```
    G: BD  (G)
    A: E   (A, Am)
    B: D   (Bm, G)
    D: A   (D, Dm) 
    E: GB  (Em)
```

Don't do other substitutions unless they fit smoothly into the harmonic movement of the piece or add a tension you want to hear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sort of...but there's a problem.

We can think of the pentatonic scale as a major scale that's missing scale-degrees 4 and 7, so in some ways we can think of the triad qualities as the same as those from major, but without the fourth and seventh chords.

So, instead of `MmmMMm°`, we have `MmmMm`. But let's look at these chords:

[image]

The middle three chords actually include the two pitches that we don't have in pentatonic! (I've parenthesized these pitches.) So it's tough to say that the `ii` chord is minor, since in a *true* pentatonic collection we actually won't have the `C` that determines whether this triad is major or minor. A more correct representation of these triads in a true pentatonic environment would be:

[image]

So although `I` and `vi` are clear, the chords built on scale-degrees 2 and 5 are both open fifth "power chords." The chord built on scale-degree 3, meanwhile, is a simple minor third.

---

With that said, there are psychological and cultural aspects that would suggest many Western listeners would hear that A open fifth as minor-ish and that D open fifth as major-ish. But the fact remains that, in a true pentatonic collection, these clarifying pitches simply are not there.

Comment: unrelated to the original question, what software did you use to make these images?

Comment: [LilyPond](http://www.lilypond.org), an open-source and text-based music notation software. I swear by it, but there is a learning curve.

Comment: @Richard Have you tried MuseScore and found yourself preferring LilyPond, or have you never worked with MuseScore? (I use MuseScore, but only because it's the first one I tried.)

Comment: @BobRodes I have used MuseScore, but I find that LilyPond is both faster and more capable.

Comment: Thanks Richard. After looking over the "learning manual" for LilyPond I can see why! As a programming language it's well put together. It seems that once you get comfortable with it it will go faster than MuseScore. One more question: do you use one of the UI apps that run with it, to get some sort of ability to play back what you write?

Comment: @BobRodes Oh, I use Frescobaldi all the time. In fact, I once thought that "real" LilyPonders didn't use any UI help, but that's outright wrong. We basically all use something, and Frescobaldi is easily the most common.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when *guitarists* talk about pentatonics, they refer to minor pents. Here, all answers refer to *major* pents. (I know the OP asks with reference to G major, but most guitarists will widdle G min. pent over that...) However, the same sort of 'problem' occurs.

There just aren't enough notes to make enough chords. There is always going to be a pattern, for each, but because the two 'iffy' notes have been taken out - making it almost impossible to play anything dissonant - the chords from the standard diatonic scale will fit under those pent. notes.